# var_dump on a MBTiles file

Tags: vector-tiles, mbtiles, maplibre-gl

Is it possible to do something simlar to var_dump() on an MBTiles files to see exactly what data is inside? So I can then see what keys I need to extract bits of (vector) data. Or is there a program that can do this (Ubuntu).

Edit: I created the vector MBTiles using Tilemaker after editing the config setting `"include_ids": true,` to get the OSM Way ID into MBTiles, I want to see if that worked and how I can access the Way ID in Maplibre.

Comment: I suppose that you have vector tiles in your MBTiles file, not raster tiles, right?

Comment: I'm using `"include_ids": true` in tilemaker, and then `QueryRenderedFeatures` from MapLibre/MapBox, and I only find mismatch between the real OSM ID and the one recorded by tilemaker in the mbtiles Currently living in Auckland, if I check the restaurant "Culprit", the OSM ID is https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/6950904685 [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOiWm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOiWm.png) while on the mbtiles it's 1106462532461 [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRKiI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRKiI.png) Any explanation ?

Answer (score 1):

MBTiles is a SQLite database so you can use any SQLite client to inspect it. The tiles are stored as binary blobs.

If you want to take a look at the contents of the tiles themselves and if they are vector tiles, you can use `ogrinfo`:

```
ogrinfo -so -al file.mbtiles layer
```

For more options consult the `ogrinfo` documentation at https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html

Comment: I tried that, appears data is stored as BLOB

Comment: Ah, you didn't say it was vector data and that you wanted to inspect the tiles contents themselves. Updated the answer.

Comment: Still can't see the Way ID. Maybe I need to rephrase the question on the assumption that enabling include_ids in the tileserver config does actually include the OSM Way ID - "How to retrieve the OSM Way ID from an OSM based vector tile source in Maplibre?"

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that enabling include_ids in the tilemaker config works, Maplibre has map.queryRenderedFeatures which might work. Protomaps has a GL demo that uses it to display a popup with the OSM Way ID referenced. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/